# Binary tree for sorting combinations

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, tree

Let's imagine to have a binary n-array as input. All the possible combinations for this n-array will be 2^n. Right?

Now, I want to put these combinations in a specific order. In particular, I want "0, 0, ...0" to be the first one, and "1, 1, ...1" the last one. I want also another rule to be respected, but it is easier to see it rather to explain it: http://postimg.org/image/qqvmq9w6n/ (the numbers are the weights for the elements of the specific row).

In the picture, the arrays are the columns, ok? So there are examples for n = 1, n = 2, n = 3, etc.

Now, let's do the tree. The positions of the combinations, plotted against the tree, will be like: http://postimg.org/image/6hplc6oxh/ . To me, it seems pretty random. I mean: I receive an n-array, I can put it on the tree, but then how do I know which number to assign it? I don't want to calculate all the possible combinations one by one. I think there is a formula, I can see that there are some rules running on the tree (image/5a11usm0j/), but it gets more and more complicated the more n increases.

Any idea on how to solve this sorting problem (whether with the tree sorting or combinatorial analysis, or whatever)?

Comment: Could you explain, for example,  `0,1,2,4,8,3,5,9,16,6,14...` order for 5-bit combinations?

Comment: You took the "green and red" series and gave them 2^n values? In that way it doesn't work and the combinations will not be ordered in the way I want. You should use the weights I suggested (the numbers on the left), in that way you will have: `0, 1, 2, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.5, 3.75, 4.5` etc (for 4-bits, similar for 5-bits).

Comment: if someone wants, I have also the "red and green" pattern for n = 6 http://postimg.org/image/m4vjxj4qd/